# Subs jobs in Jenkins MultiJob Project not waiting for other to complete and triggering their downstream job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins Multijob Project which are running two sub jobs Job1 and Job2 .The issue I am facing is that Job2 is completed and it starts triggering its downstream job while Job1 is still running. I want Job1 to wait for Job2 before triggering its downstream.

Comment: So I am using a jenkins pipeline which is having downstream jobs, so job1 and job2 has their down streams. When I start with multijob,both jobs are running in parallel but when job 2 completes it is starting with its downstream job without waiting for job1 to complete.

Comment: i have found the solution for that, I have used Build Blocker plugin which resolved the issue.